# Bootstrap-sass 3.3.6 + Bower = no glyphicon

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bower, glyphicons

I've installed in my project `"bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.6"`through Bower. In my `index.html` I've got injected autoamticaly this:

```
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

and in my `style.scss` I put this:

```
@import '../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';
```

What am I missing to get glyphicons working?

Answer (score 0):

glyphicons is a fonts that instead of showing chars its shows vector images

so in order to show the icon you need, beside adding the sass, make sure that the font on the dist folder is in the relative path so that the css `@font-face` will load properly

you can check the path by open the network (in chrome) and you should see an error of 404 for the font path

Comment: I've no 404, so I suppose that I need to write down the @font-face directive in my scss, right?

Comment: i look at the [bootstap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) in github and see that the name of the @import file is `@import '../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap'` with an underscore on the start